# How to represent that all classes of a package implements an interface

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am trying to model a MVC architecture for a little website.
My models are all in a model package, and I have a model interface that all model should implements.
So my question was about that implementation. Is it possible to do it like so ?

[image]

And if it's wrong is there any way to say that all classes of a package implements an interface ?

Answer (score 3):

No. That would be wrong. You need to draw the implementation relation for each class that implements the interface.

[image]

Comment: So there is really no other ways ? I have like twenty classes in the package, and it'll make it unreadable if I add an implementation relation for all of them.

Comment: You need to distinguish between your model and your diagrams. UML is not about diagramming.